# How do I delete all Music off my iPhone library so nothing appears?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music.app

I’m having problems deleting all my music off my iPhone.

I have deleted the music through iTunes and tried to delete it on on my iPhone but it still shows the track and just has the download symbol next to it.

How do I make it delete off my music library completely?

Comment: Sounds like you might have iTunes Match turned on - this will link to your iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

I had no choice but to remove all music from my iPhone. I have had music intrude in on my 3rd party apps playlists and even phone calls on bluetooth in multiple vehicles. This is a ridiculous solution to a problem I hope is fixed soon.

I tried to go straight to step 5 but Music app was not in the list for me delete to select (iPhone 6 plus iOS <= 8.1.2)

1. **Settings > Music** - toggle "Show All Music" to off.
2. Open music app - identify all songs that are on your device.
3. **Settings > Music** - toggle "Show All Music" to on.
4. Download the songs from step 2.
5. **Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage > Music > Edit > All Songs > Delete**
6. **(Optional) Settings > Cellular** - In "Use cellular data for" locate Music App and toggle off.
7. **Settings > Music** - toggle "Show All Music" to off.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings-->Usage-->Manage Storage-->Music and where it says "All Songs" swipe to the left and hit delete. You can do the same for Videos too by going to Settings-->Usage-->Manage Storage-->Videos and swiping left to delete

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the songs from showing up on your IOS devices music library, go to:
Settings > Music > Show All Music. Then turn this feature off. This will only show music that has been downloaded to this device.